# EF friendly way to update child collections whose relationship is a mapping table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

For some reason I can't update child collections using Entity Framework.  I have the following schema which has been generated in an .edmx.

```
MainRecord        RecordType        RecordTypeMap

MainRecordID      RecordTypeID      RecordTypeMap       
[Other fields]    RecordTypeName    RecordTypeID
```

The RecordType table holds a small list of RecordTypes, the idea is to use the mapping table.
A MainRecord can have more than one RecordType, so the RecordTypeMap table might look like the following:

```
MainRecordID    RecordTypeID                
1002             1
1002             2
1003             1
1004             2
1004             3
1004             4
```

The way that EF generates this is that it knows that this is a mapping table, and my MainRecord objects have a collection of RecordTypes.  The problems are that the wrong information seems to go into the database when I attempt to add, edit, or delete these records.  If I am adding a new MainRecord with a call like:

```
context.MainRecords.Add(record);
```

The RecordTypes for this particular MainRecord end up in the RecordType table with new RecordTypeIDs, instead of in the RecordTypeMap table with an existing RecordTypeID.  I have tried a number of permutations for editing and deleting these RecordTypes from their association with the MainRecord.  While I can hack a solution, isn't there an EF-friendly way to perform the mapping function above?  I'm using EF6.

EDIT:  How can I made the below code edit the RecordType records associated with the MainRecord?  The 'Add' section of the code works fine, although why it works when the entity state is considered 'modified' for the RecordType is beyond me...

Here is the code that saves the record.  If there is an obvious syntax problem it is a transcription error.

```
        public bool SaveRecord(MainRecord record)
        {
            using (var context = new DBEntities())
            {
                var existingRecord = context.MainRecords.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MainRecordID == record.MainRecordID);

                if (existingContact != null)
                {
                    context.Entry(existingRecord).CurrentValues.SetValues(record);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Add new record.
                    context.MainRecords.Add(record);

                    // The below properly adds entries with the existing keys into the Map table.
                    // Not sure why this does that, it doesn't look like it would on the surface.
                    foreach (var type in contact.tblContactTypes)
                    {
                        context.Entry(type).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how you're creating the MainRecord? Specifically, how you're defining the RecordTypes associated with it. 
I'm asking because, if you're adding existing EF entities to the RecordTypes collection that MainRecord has, EF should do the mapping properly instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Posted the code I'm using for the add / edit.  I had a lot of other things that I tried, but they created issues, rather than solved them.

Comment: If by "EF-friendly way" you mean some magic method, there isn't. In case of adding, you need to resolve (attach existing) items from `record.RecordTypes` collection *before* calling `Add(record)`. For update it's more complicated. Check SO for "many-to-many relationship with implicit join table", I'm pretty sure you'll find an examples of doing what you need.

Comment: In my experience, the solution to the "implicit many-to-many junction table" problem is usually to make the junction table an *explicit* entity, and manage it myself, instead of allowing EF to try and perform its "magic".

Comment: Will investigate the above recommendations.  I tried a number of variations of going through the collection of types and modifying the EntityState, but that didn't solve the problem.  The fact that it is saving to the 'Type' table instead of the 'Mapping' table when it does save is odd to me, especially since EF sort of hides the mapping table and attempts to show just the relationship..